# Aurelia get-started browser error

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm trying the http://aurelia.io/get-started.html project, and after installing everything, i get the following error in chrome console:

[image]
**And this is the error in Firefox**

[image]

Comment: Are you using a release or trying to pull down the master branch?

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/releases/tag/0.12.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it !

I typed value.*bond* instead of value.**bind** in the markup

app.html:

```
<template>
  <section>
    <h2>${heading}</h2>

    <form role="form" submit.delegate="welcome()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fn">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" value.bond="firstName" class="form-control" id="fn" placeholder="first name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ln">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" value.bond="lastName" class="form-control" id="ln" placeholder="last name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Full Name</label>
        <p class="help-block">${fullName}</p>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </section>
</template>
```